# If multiple people report a security vulnerability which is not fixed, should everybody get the credit or only the first person?

Tags: vulnerability, disclosure

I reported a vulnerability to an organization X and they claim that they already know about it and are working towards a fix?

I am wondering if multiple people report the same vulnerability to an organization, should everybody get the credit? Should I still get the credit for the vulnerability?

Comment: The organisation only considers the first report they receive. Resolving an issue can take a few weeks or even months. They can't consider everyone in that time frame for rewards. Also, people might send duplicate entries then using a friend's account.

Comment: I consider this off-topic here. Apart from that look at other kinds of detections, i.e. inventions or patents. Usually (but not always) the first one publishing/reporting it gets the credit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about just giving credit then it would seem polite for the Company to credit reporters of an undisclosed vulnerability. See [this post](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/02/simultaneous_di.html) for example.

If you are talking about a reward then convention is that it will generally go to the first finder. In [this post](https://blog.bugcrowd.com/three-ways-to-avoid-duplicates-in-bug-bounty-programs/), the CEO of BugCrowd (they run bug bounty programs) mentions that they give "Kudos" but hints that only the first reporter gets the reward.